# Add to db using setter

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

When it's not found in db, add on w/o removing existing data.

I've tried object = new object(); to add.

```
Object o = objectDao.findByName("A");

if (o == null) {
o = new Object();
o.setName("B");
}
```

This will add NEW list of data when NULL.
But I want NEW list while keeping the old one.

Comment: Since you already have a DAO, why not call the corresponding `save` or `add` method in it?

Comment: Yes, I am using objectDao.save(o); in the end. It wipes out all the data and saves new one

Comment: Then that seems to be an issue with your Dao rather than the code you have posted in the question'

Comment: I'm using CrudRepository

Comment: and w/o    o = new Object();  it will update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out.

I had to create a model with an @id that is @GeneratedValue so that it will keep on increasing, not starting from 1 every-time when we use the save method.